doing operations for else-if "groups"
I had a pattern like this and didn't know a good way to handle it


let i = Math.floor(5 * Math.random())

if (i == 0) {
    console.log('a')
    console.log('+')
}
else if (i == 1) {
    console.log('b')
    console.log('+')
}
else if (i == 2) {
    console.log('c')
    console.log('+')
}
else if (i == 3) {
    console.log('d')
    console.log('-')
}
else if (i == 4) {
    console.log('e')
    console.log('-')
}



I'm using a multiple else-if statements and want to do an operation when one of the conditions of a "group" is qualified.
(consider all the condition checks completely disparate)
The project was very minimal. This part is at its core and will be called many
times. Any impact on performance is important, so I avoid using any unnecessary
variable definition or object, array creation. The size of the bundle matters
as well.
I know that the difference would not be that big if I used some data structures
to keep track of the state and do the corresponding operation but, I think this
one is pretty neat and performant. Check it out:


let i = Math.floor(5 * Math.random()),
    skipped = false

if (i == 0) {
    console.log('a')
}
else if (i == 1) {
    console.log('b')
}
else if (i == 2) {
    console.log('c')
}
else if ((skipped = true) && false) {}
else if (i == 3) {
    console.log('d')
}
else if (i == 4) {
    console.log('e')
}

if (skipped) console.log('-')
else console.log('+')



The only place that I could do an operation without breaking the else if
chain was another else if block's check. Then I had to add && false to keep
the chain going. I shared to see how you would handle this situation, it does
work perfectly, but I feel like I'm violating something :D Also kinda shocked
when I find out how rare this situation was. Probably they didn't think a
language need this functionality natively.

For switch-case statements, this can be done without the weird assignment place:
switch (i) {...}
skipped = true
switch (i) {...}

since they check the exact string and only one can match, this is safe if we
hard-code the cases uniquely. But for else if statements, if I break one of
them and start again, another else if can be fired after one has been fired
in the chain above. Since they are not in the same chain, nothing restricts it.
As I said, all the conditions are disparate, so multiple conditions can be
true (unlike uniquely hard-coded switch cases).
btw even this is possible with switch:
switch (i) {
    // ...
    case i:
        skipped = true
    // ...
    case i: 
        skipped = idk
}

also this whole time, it's not just a split-in-two thing. I could give a number
to skipped and use that in the next if to do the corresponding operation.
For the sake of simplicity, I used a boolean.

So, is there a better way to do an operation for a "group"? I don't think an assignment in the place of a condition check is a good practice (no need to say it's not a best) but at the same time, I cannot find any better way

So what is the actual question?

@mplungjan is there a better way to do this? I feel like it's wrong to do an assignment in an elif's check

if ((skipped = true) && false) {} is never true, because of the assignment of true and logical AND with false.

btw, what result do you expect? what is skipped doing?

@NinaScholz that's the point. if it would be true then the chain would have been broken and the rest of the else if statements would be dead. I only used this check to do an operation without breaking the else if. may I want you to read the whole question and tell me if something is still unclear?

So far it is const pair=["a+","b+","c+","d-","e-"][i];console.log(pair.charAt(0));console.log(pair.charAt(1));

@NinaScholz skipped is used to determine the "else-if groups" which the whole question is all about

@tevemadar "(consider all the condition checks completely disparate)" what does this line tell you?  then let me clearify it one more, the i == 1 is just for the illustrative purpose. this can be Array.isArray(i) && i[76][0] != "@" but I didn't want to spread your attention to that and focus on the "groups"

You could take labeled block statement and exit/break early.


let i = Math.floor(5 * Math.random()),
    skipped = false;

block: {
    if (i == 0) {
        console.log('a');
        break block;
    }
    if (i == 1) {
        console.log('b');
        break block;
    }
    if (i == 2) {
        console.log('c');
        break block;
    }
    skipped = true;
    if (i == 3) {
        console.log('e');
        break block;
    }
    if (i == 4) {
        console.log('e');
    }
}

if (skipped) console.log('-');
else console.log('+');




Essentially a "switch-case-ish if" nice :D glad to put my time to articulate the situation. I've also made some additions to eliminate the break and use multiple groups, see my answer

Using labeled block is a great idea Nina! But the breaks are not really needed since they are else ifs and one and only one will get fired. Also it's like the curse of the switch case, so I just made a clearer way to separate it. Here's a simplified version with multiple groups handled elegantly. But the essence is from @Nina Scholz's answer


let i = Math.floor(5 * Math.random()),
    skipped = 1;

block: {
    // group 1
    if      (i == 0) console.log('a')
    else if (i == 1) console.log('b')
    else if (i == 2) console.log('c')
    else skipped = 2

    if  (skipped == 1) break block

    // group 2
    if      (i == 3) console.log('e')
    else if (i == 4) console.log('e')
    else skipped = 3

    if (skipped == 2) break block
        
    // group 3
    // ...
}

if      (skipped == 1) console.log('+') // operation after group 1 activated
else if (skipped == 2) console.log('-') // operation after group 2 activated




you may check if early break with only if is faster/slower than else if structure.

@NinaScholz I'm pretty sure that yours is faster. Mine literally has an additional check and wrapped the assignment in else. also standalone if has no disadvantage over else if if the next if isn't going to be run anyways (since we break) and probably will be a bit faster since it's more kinda "stateless". I just removed the "break in every if" from your answer to try to make it a more appealing. but you got the performance)

To handle this pattern more efficiently in JavaScript,you can use array
const characters = ["a","b","c","d","e"];
const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length);
const selectedChar = characters[randomIndex];
const operator = (selectedChar >='a' && selectedChar <= 'c') ? "+" : "-";

console.log(selectedChar);
console.log(operator)


Surprisingly, accessing array might not always be faster than if-else condition especially for small enough cases (in this case there's only 5 elements). Anyway, premature optimization is the root of all evil.

dude... I repeatedly said that the checks are for illustrative purposes and even have given an example with switch-case statement (which has already solved this exact situation better and in a more extensive way than yours)

@AngYC you are right but the array solution is already completely irrelevant. My checks are NOT based on digit or index nor they are unique. I used this to demonstrate you a working check. You should have considered them as independent checks. For example, a chain of 2 conditions can be, true false, false true, false false, AND true true. Then you'll take the first true as the nature of else-if. The checks cannot be generalized like sidharth's answer

I understand, I am just pointing out that array is not always faster as the goal of the OP is to have better performance.
